# Plano de fundo e icone no tableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui

Gostaria de saber, como que faço para adicionar em um `tableView` à propriedade de `background` e `icone`? Já consigo adicionar o `Background` agora está faltando o icon.

Código:

```
class tableView : public QSqlTableModel
  {
      Q_OBJECT
      public:
         tableView(QObject * parent = 0, QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase())
         : QSqlTableModel(parent,db) {;}
         QVariant data ( const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const
         {
             if(role==Qt::BackgroundColorRole) {
               const QVariant value(data(index,Qt::DisplayRole));
                                  if(value.toString()=="Sim"){
                                      return QVariant(QColor("#d0ffe3")); //<<background 
                                  }else if (value.toString()=="Não"){
                                      return QVariant(QColor("#ffe3d0")); //<<background 
                                  }else if (value.toString()=="Neutro"){
                                      return QVariant(QColor("#fffad0")); //<<background 
                                  }
             }
            return QSqlTableModel::data(index,role);
         }
 };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando a view solicitar uma DecorationRole, basta retornar um QPixmap, que pode funcionar tanto uma imagem de fundo quanto um ícone, ou mesmo retornar um QIcon:

```
if(role==Qt::BackgroundColorRole) {
   const QVariant value(data(index,Qt::DisplayRole));

   if(value.toString()=="Sim"){
      return QVariant(QColor("#d0ffe3")); //<<background 
   }else if (value.toString()=="Não"){
      return QVariant(QColor("#ffe3d0")); //<<background 
   }else if (value.toString()=="Neutro"){
      return QVariant(QColor("#fffad0")); //<<background 
   }
} elseif (role==Qt::DecorationRole) {
   return QPixmap( "/caminho/pra/imagem/de/teste.jpg" );

   // Depois você vai ter que adaptar ao seu critério de
   // onde vai pegar o icone desejado.
   // Pode usar a mesma lógica do bloco de cima, mas em vez
   // de QColor devolva um QIcon ou QPixmap
}
```

Comment: Retorna tudo no QVariant? como que ficaria este código para retorna todos objetos Qpixmap,qicon,qcolor?

Comment: Editei pra melhorar o exemplo

Comment: ok, muito obrigado.

Comment: @user628298 a função é chamada várias vazes. Cada vez com um role diferente.

Comment: Agora deu certo, Mas no segundo `if` tem que trocar `Qt::BackgroundColorRole` para `Qt::DisplayRole`. Obrigado

Comment: @user628298 na verdade é Qt::DecorationRole, eu tinha editado errado

Comment: @Bacco Você sabe como aumentar o tamanho do icon?

Comment: @user628298 Aumentar pra ficar diferente da imagem original?

Comment: @Bacco Aumenta o tamanho do Qicon na exibição. O ícone tem 32x32, mas na exibição do tableView. Ele aparece super pequeno +- 10x10.

Comment: @Bacco Consegui. Estava procurando na class `QIcon` em vez da class `QtableView`. `ui->tableView->setIconSize(QSize(32, 32));`